# Update global variable from workflow

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

```
function function1(){
    Param($a)    
    "YOU HAVE entered : $a"
    $arr+=$a    
    $arr2.Add($a)
}

workflow wf{
    Param($b)
    Parallel{
        sequence{
            function1 $b
        }
    }
}

$arr = @()
$arr2 = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@()
wf -b 10
$arr
$arr2
```

The output I am getting as below

```
YOU HAVE entered : 10

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At wf:12 char:12
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

I am unable to update both the arrays which I declared outside the function and workflow.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user2906717 There is no other choice than inserting the function inside the workflow, threads can't communicate together except passing parameters in the workflow. You can just return results from the workflow. Use [runspaces](https://www.google.fr/search?q=powershell+runspaces) to get more options.

Comment: I tried putting function inside workflow. I am still getting the same error.